# Question related to Fréchet space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, distribution-theory, locally-convex-spaces

I would like to know if the following property that is true for Banach spaces,  it holds for Fréchet space as well.

The question is:

Let $X$ be a Banach reflexive space and $Y$ be a Fréchet space.  Suppose that $ X ⊂ Y$ dense and the
injection of $X$ in $Y$ continuous. Then: $$L^{\infty} (0,T;X)\cap C_w([0,T]  ;Y)= C_w([0,T]  ;X),  $$ 
Where $C_w([0, T]; Y)$, we represent the space of weakly continuous functions form $[0, T]$ into
$Y$. This means that if $u \in C_w([0,T]  ;Y)$,  the mapping $$t\mapsto \langle u(t), y'\rangle$$ is continuous on $[0, T]$ for all $y' \in Y′$ dual
of $ Y.$?